# Tizen scrollable watch face

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

Not sure if I'm going to have any luck here, but the response I got on the Samsung forum didn't sound certain this would work.  I want to make a watch face for the gear s2 that also has the ability to scroll when viewing particular divs.  I'm building it with html/css/javascript.  I first took a template app which has the ability to scroll and assigned that the category of watch face.  When I installed it, it lost it's ability to scroll.  The Samsung forum mentioned to try utilizing canvas.  I'm very knew to programming, so this will take a little research and considerable trial and error.  I'm willing to give it a shot, but I worry it's not even possible to start with.  I'd hate to waste a lot of time and energy if the watch face category overrides any attempts to scroll by design.  Especially because I have alternative options, just not as ideal.  Anyone have any knowledge about this?

Comment: did my answer help you ?

Comment: Yes, but due to my inexperience both programming and on this site I was afraid to mark it official.  Since your answer was so different than the response on the Samsung's forum I wasn't sure how to know what answers were 100% accurate.  Since the status bar action is only involved if you're swiping from the very top, I wasn't certain that scrolling via swipe was impossible.  I felt I needed to test that sometime before marking the answer official.

Comment: Yes ... That was my previous though... but after some study i found some info and posted on this question. 
http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=307256&topCtgy=03#postId307256

Comment: Yep, that was my post in the Samsung forum.  The same person that quoted your post here was the same person that said scroll via canvas swipe may work.  Your answer definitely looks right, I was just hoping for more confirmation.  I still think I'm going to test it at some point in the near future ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will not be possible currently. Look on Gear Home screen,

- On left Tap or Anti-clockwise Bezel Rotation, Notification Board is shown
- On left Tap  or Clockwise Bezel Rotation, Widget Board is shown
  [image]

So, it is clear that you can't use Bezel to scroll on Home Screen (Watch Face) of Gear.

In case of up-down swipe on top part, there is Status Bar action. So you can't use Bezel and Up-down Swipe to Scroll. One thing you can do here, is to add an up arrow button to scroll up and a down arrow button to scroll down.

Smart decision will be if you develop separate application to meet your requirements and add icons on Watch Face to launch these apps. 
For example, email and Heart Rate to show some summary data and to launch these apps from these icons.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since I had already split my data up into sections, I just add small up and down buttons over in the margin with an onClick function: to scroll down I just hide the topmost (visible) section; to scroll up just make it visible.  Reasonably intuitive and effective.